# Electric Potential-Electric Field Relationship

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

[image]
In my book its given-At point A(closer to electric field) the potential is v but at point B(farther from electric field) potential is v+dv.How is it possible as we know that potential decreases if we move far from the electric field?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583). Also, please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: By "closer to the electric field" I assume you mean "closer to the source of the electric field".  Is that true?   If so, consider that the sign of the charge of the source is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your general assumtion is incorrect, since it's a matter of where your point of reference is positioned. In general we use infinity to achieve mathematical simplicity. Although specific cases may arise, where your configuration extends to infinity and you're constrained to use another reference point. Your book supposedly did not use infinity as a standard point of reference.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between electric potential and electric field is:
$$\Delta V=-\int \vec E \cdot d\vec l $$ which you must calculate with respect to a point. Therefore it is usually said that we calculate the integral with $r$ coming from infinity to the point we want to calculate. Therefore it can be proved that $$\Delta V=\frac{kq}{r}.$$

So by moving from point $a$ to point $b$ we can prove that :
$V_a - V_b > 0$ .

I hope this gives your answer :)